# Retrieve Google Chrome Ubuntu favicon

Tags: 11.10, google-chrome, cache, bookmarks

Where the favicon .ico file is stored in Ubuntu 11.10?

How can I extract the .ico file from the chrome cache?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you type <kbd>about:cache</kbd> in the address bar of Google Chrome and hit enter, you'll get a page of the items stored in cache. You can then use **control+F** to search for "favico". You can then copy and paste the relevant url into a new tab to load the favicon and then save it to your disk using **control+S**.

**Edit**:
If you want to recover "favicons" corresponding to bookmarks, first export the bookmarks using *Wrench*, *Bookmarks*, *Bookmark Manager*, *Organize*, and *Export Bookmarks to HTML file*.
Now, open the exported HTML file with a text editor like gedit or Geany.
Inspect the file for the bookmark of interest. Here is an example of an entry in my exported bookmarks.html file:

```
<DT><A HREF="https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BasicSecurity" ADD_DATE="1320507266" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">BasicSecurity - Ubuntu Wiki</A>
```

Note the **ICON="data:image/png;base64**. In other words, the favicon image is stored as a data URI. Copy the contents *between* the double quotes that follow **ICON=** and that precede **>BasicSecurity** (exclude the quotes) and paste it into the address bar of Chrome or Firefox and hit enter to view the favicon as an image. The image can be saved as usual by right-clicking and choosing *save image as ...*

You don't need a net connection for this or even the browser's cache.

I should mention that the answer was based on Kari's answer over [here](https://superuser.com/questions/93056/change-a-favicon-locally-in-google-chrome).

> Export your bookmarks to the desktop.
>   Open the bookmarks file in notepad.
>   The structure is self-explanatory once you study the file.
>   The long streams of random characters are the image data for each favicon.

Comment: What if that site's down, ie, cannot connect to the server via the internet to fetch the server-side favicon.However, the favicon just cached by google chrome somewhere in the system and the favicon still showing in the bookmark bar. I just wanna know where the cached favicons usually put.

Comment: Added more information.