# How can I delete Google Chrome Favicon Cache on Ubuntu?

Tags: google-chrome

There are [several articles](http://www.nullalo.com/en/how-to-delete-google-chrome-favicon-cache/) that outlined how to delete the Favicon cache on Mac OS X and Windows but not Linux.

Does anyone know where the directory lies on Ubuntu Linux that contains the favicon cache?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/93014/retrieve-google-chrome-ubuntu-favicon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `locate` command to find it:

```
locate -i chrom | grep -i fav
```

I'm using chromium and the output is:

```
/home/ravexina/.config/chromium/Default/Favicons
/home/ravexina/.config/chromium/Default/Favicons-journal
```

Remove the first one and you're done:

```
rm  /home/ravexina/.config/chromium/Default/Favicons
```

For "Google Chrome" the path should be the same, however if this file does not exist in your system, use `locate` command to find it.